# Scale wordpress website to fit all screen sizes

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, web, media-queries

We have built a website using wordpress and the zeyn template provided by detheme.

The theme is responsive and mobile optimised. The website is currently under development at www.techmorphosis-development.com/rby/

The client wants a behavior similar to https://www.templeandwebster.com.au/ when viewed through a mobile device. ie, the website should automatically scale down to fit the device screen and not re-structure it self like it is currently doing at www.techmorphosis-development.com/rby/.

I've had a play around with media queries but had no luck.

Any help in achieving this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: That's because the site in question (Temple and Webster) is not responsive. It DOES NOT SCALE. Sounds like your client wants an adaptive site. Not a responsive one though.